# javascript loop error

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, mapbox

I'm stuck with my loop. Everything functions, except `markerLayer.markers()[i].showTooltip();`
Somehow it shows the wrong marker. Am I passing the wrong arguments? Am I missing the logic here?

```
for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
    var a = side.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
    a.onclick = (function (feature, i) {
        return function () {
            markerLayer.interaction.hideTooltips()
            map.ease.location({
                lat: feature.geometry.coordinates[1],
                lon: feature.geometry.coordinates[0]
            }).zoom(zoomPlaces).optimal(null, null, function (feature) {
                markerLayer.markers()[i].showTooltip();
            })
        }
    })
    (features[i], i);
}
```

Comment: Does `markerLayer.markers()` return the markers in the order you expect?

Comment: No, I will explain:
The normal order is 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
Now I get 2 6 3 4 5 0 1

If I make it `markerLayer.markers()[i+1].showTooltip();`, it returns 6 3 4 5 0 1 (the last one doesn't work)

If I make it +2, it gives 3 4 5 0 1 / /
If I make it -1, it gives / 2 6 3 4 5 0 (3, 4, 5 is correct)
If I make it -2, it gives / / 2 6 3 4 5 (2 is correct)
Any thoughts?

Comment: The whole code is at http://www.boerenmetwater.nl

Comment: It appears to be rather random but it does show up in the same order every time.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of MapBox and Leaflet's JavaScript APIs use `map.markerLayer.getLayers()` to return array of layer objects that contains a unique `_leaflet_id`. Please use that id number to help specify the marker you'd like to `togglePopup`.